# Replace a global library with a new version in Grails

Tags: grails, protocol-buffers

Grails comes with Protobuf 2.4.1 as a 'global dependency', but my app uses a library that compiled against Protobuf 2.5.0 (and version 2.5.0 isn't compatible with 2.4.1).

The problem that I don't see any way to tell Grails to use only specified version instead of bundled. If I exclude it in `BuildConfig` it just excluded from application, all versions. I mean:

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes 'protobuf-java'
}

dependencies {
    //build 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0'
    // or
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0'
}
```

Grails fails with:

```
Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException:
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/MessageOrBuilder
```

How I can exclude global library, and add it as a new dependency instead? I'm using Grails 2.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to `exclude` `protobuf-java`. The newest version, when provided as a dependency, should **evict** the older one. So v2.4.1 will be evicted by v2.5.0.

```
inherits("global") {
    //excludes 'protobuf-java'
}

dependencies {
    build 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0'
}
```

The above should be good. To witness the same, run a `dependency-report` on the grails app and look for the dependency.

To support with facts, I tested it and it works perfectly for me.

```
import com.google.protobuf.TextFormat
//Just to replicate your issue, but it did not complain about this import.
import com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder 
class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        TextFormat t = new TextFormat()
        println t
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}

//Prints:
com.google.protobuf.TextFormat@372688e8
```

Comment: Sadly, but it doesn't work on my environment :( fails with `java.lang.VerifyError: class ... overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;` And dependency reports show boths versions in classpath

Comment: Try `grails clean && grails compile`. The ivy report would show both but one should be evicted.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Can you provide me a simple snippet which uses api particular to v2.5.0? I would like to test that as well.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I tried importing `MessageOrBuilder` it did not complain me either. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Finally got it working! Seems that I had some wrong configuration, now it's working as you said. Thanks!

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Glad I was able to assist. :-)

Comment: @dmahapatro Hello there. May I know what's the configuration like? Because I'm facing the same problem as you.

Comment: @KevinTan Should be asking to IgorArtamonov. :)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov May I know what's the config like?

Comment: @dmahapatro whoops. :P

Comment: @KevinTan don't have this code now. but as I remember, it was just a mess with dependencies, etc. also try grails clean, etc